# node-sass doesn't install on vsCode

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, sass, node-sass

I have created a ReactJS project which was functioning perfectly and was hosted. Unfortunately, it has stopped working completely for some time now, and it seems to be related to different errors I have between dependency versions. Despite trying everything, nothing seems to work anymore. Therefore, I tried creating a brand new project to see if the problem persisted. When I run 'npm i node-sass,' I get this huge error message telling me that I have deprecated libraries, issues with Python, and so on.

```
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'D:\\wamp64\\www\\ReactJS\\reupload-portofolio\\node_modules\\cacache',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'D:\wamp64\www\ReactJS\reupload-portofolio\node_modules\cacache\node_modules\@npmcli\fs\lib\common\file-url-to-path'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'scandir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'D:\\wamp64\\www\\ReactJS\\reupload-portofolio\\node_modules\\cacache\\node_modules\\@npmcli\\fs\\lib\\common\\file-url-to-path'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\wamp64\www\ReactJS\reupload-portofolio\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\wamp64\www\ReactJS\reupload-portofolio\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\\wamp64\\www\\ReactJS\\reupload-portofolio\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@19.8.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking Python explicitly set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "--python=" or "npm config get python" is "C:\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Python311\python.exe" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executable path is "C:\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Python311\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - version is "3.11.1"
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.1 found at "C:\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 19.8.1
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '19.8.1' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "19.8.1"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 19.8.1
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 19.8.1
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: D:\wamp64\www\ReactJS\reupload-portofolio\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? Yes
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32901.82) found at:
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - missing any Windows SDK
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32901.82) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any Windows SDK
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (D:\wamp64\www\ReactJS\reupload-portofolio\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\wamp64\www\ReactJS\reupload-portofolio\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (D:\wamp64\www\ReactJS\reupload-portofolio\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\wamp64\www\ReactJS\reupload-portofolio\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\wamp64\www\ReactJS\reupload-portofolio\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\wamp64\www\ReactJS\reupload-portofolio\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\wamp64\www\ReactJS\reupload-portofolio\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:427:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:512:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\wamp64\\www\\ReactJS\\reupload-portofolio\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\wamp64\www\ReactJS\reupload-portofolio\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v19.8.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jérémy\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-17T15_48_04_686Z-debug-0.log
```

The problem is that when I try to update har-validator or uuid, nothing gets updated (even in administrator mode). Moreover, I have installed two versions of Python (2.x and 3.x), but the error persists. Can someone help me? I don't know what else to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "_I have created a ReactJS project which was functioning perfectly and was hosted. Unfortunately, it has stopped working completely for some time now_" - so what changed to make it stop working? Please be precise. The dependencies did not change on their own in a deployed/hosted app.

Comment: i don't do any change. It was deploy on Heroku